# Prove Θ(n) + O(n^2) ≠ Θ(n^2)

Tags: asymptotics

How would I go about proving this statement?

```
Θ(n) + O(n^2) ≠ Θ(n^2)
```

I know how to prove if given a function f(n) if it's big o but I do not understand how to go about this type of problem.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: What if you start by writing down the definition of Θ(n) and O(n)? Once you do this, the answer is blatantly obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of Θ and O as sets (the sets of function satisfying the asymptotic conditions) : you need to prove set difference, i.e. give a function in the left-hand part that does not belong to the right-hand part.

An example would be

$$ f(n) = n + n $$

Clearly $f(n) \in Θ(n) + O(n^2)$. However, $\frac{f(n)}{n^2} = 2/n$, which shows that $f(n)\not \in  Θ(n^2)$.